# simple-oauth2 token is coming back blank

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using [simple-oauth2](https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2/). I've got the authorization part working, and I'm getting a code back from the API. However, when I attempt to create a token from that code using simple-oauth2's authCode.getToken function, the result is blank.

```
oauth2.authCode.getToken({
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: credentials.redirect_uri
}, callback);

function callback(err, result){
    console.log(result)
    token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
}
```

That console.log statement returns absolutely nothing, not even "undefined." Tokens created with this blank result have an empty string as the "token" property inside the returned object, like so:

```
{ create: [Function: create],
token: '',
expired: [Function: expired],
refresh: [Function: refresh],
revoke: [Function: revoke] }
```

This code is copied nearly verbatim from the examples page, and I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my config.site URL just had http, not https, and so wasn't returning anything. Adding the "s" fixed it.

Comment: where you fixed the issue in the code? What is the config.site? I am facing the same issue.